# Building a screen capture

Tags: c#, windows, screen-capture, video-recording

I'm trying to build a simple video recording of a specific window by taking a screenshot of the window every `x` milliseconds (then combine all those images in an AVI file) but I don't how to define the value of `x`. How do I define it? what is a common value used to this? I read something about 24fps.

I'm also unsure if using a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), doing the capture in the `Tick` event is a good idea. Will I have any kind of inaccurate and I should use something else? for example, for any reason the screenhot take long than expected to be taken.

My current implementation is like this:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT r);

    public Bitmap GetScreenshot(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                RECT rc;

                if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                using (var gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
                    bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
                    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
                    if (!succeeded)
                    {
                        gfxBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
                    }
                    IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);
                    Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);
                    if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
                    {
                        gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
                        gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                    }
                    return bmp;
                }
            }
```

and

```
    int i = 0;
    const string dest_path = @"C:\Users\pc2\Desktop\images";
    void doRecord()
    {
        string filename = Path.Combine(dest_path, string.Format("{0}.png", ++i));
         // yeah, I'll add some error checking here soon as it gets working.
        GetScreenshot(handle).Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

and in the Timer's tick event I call it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doRecord();
        }
```

Also how to properly define value of `x`, am I missing something?

Comment: i had a similar challenge and the found the solution was to keep sending the images to memory then have an another thread pull an image in intervals.  Yes, its *hacky* but my timeline was perfect for the recording.  Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the 'Interval' parameter for the timer that you are using. The 'Interval' is set in milliseconds, so if you want to have a ~24 FPS  set the 'Interval' to 42 (1000 (milliseconds in a second) / 24 (desired FPS) = 42).

Comment: Sorry if this isn't clear, my question is what's a good interval to take the screnshot. I'm aware how to set time's interval property.

Comment: Most usually the FPS you should aim for is 30 (but a value closer to your monitors refresh rate, which is usually 60, would be better..) - this eliminates the screen flicker and if you are to merge the pictures into a video, that should be quite nice.